# Why i am getting " Welcome To Apiato" message even after specifying my route End-Point?

Tags: php, laravel, apiato

http://localhost/public/v1/createorders, is my URL to create order API, but I am getting "welcome to apiato" message.

This message usually comes if my route is like this "http://localhost/public/v1/ ".

But i am getting this message even after changing the api endpoint.

I have apiato setup on my local computer. I have changed the hosts and vhosts file as it was mentioned.

Sometimes the API works. Sometimes the API returns 'Welcome to Apiato message'.

I was expecting my API endpoint to display a valid result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this type of problem using Postman for my testing. I was trying to register a new user and got the "welcome to apiato" message.  Postman by default sets the Accept header as * / *.  I removed the default Accept header and added Accept application/json.

Thanks to the creator of apiato Mohammad Alavi for giving this answer